# Converting Wickets DateTimeField element to Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wicket, bootstrap-datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to convert my wicket applications DateTimeField element to Bootstrap [Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I am new to Wicket framework.

html:

```
<span wicket:id="dateValue" style="width:400px">Date editor</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        var idDate = jQuery('[name*="dateValue"]').attr('id');
        console.log("idDate:"+idDate);
        jQuery('#' +idDate).datetimepicker(
            {
                useCurrent: false,
                collapse: true
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Java:

```
private final DateTimeField valueDatePicker;
valueDatePicker = addValueDatePicker(this, "dateValue", new Model<Date>());

private DateTimeField addValueDatePicker(final MarkupContainer parent, final String id, final IModel<Date> model)
{
    final DateTimeField result = new DateTimeField(id, model) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure()
        {
            boolean required = true;
            setVisibilityAllowed(required);
            setRequired(required);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean use12HourFormat()
        {
            return false;
        }

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        protected DateTextField newDateTextField(final String id, final PropertyModel<Date> dateFieldModel)
        {
            return DateTextField.forDatePattern(id, model, BooleanUtils.isFalse(TimeZoneUtility
                    .getUSDateFormatConfig()) ? DateUtility.DATE_NON_US_FORMAT : DateUtility.DATE_FORMAT);
        }
    };
    result.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    parent.add(result);
    return result;
}
```

It works, but only partially. i.e. DateTimeField provides date field text box which is showing now bootstrap multiselect calerndar, however still displays calendar, hour and min text boxes. I wanted to get rid of calendar, hour and minutes text boxes and just show only date field text box.

Comment: Do you want to use datetimepicker component just to get date part without hours and minutes? In this case add `format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'` option, see docs of [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) and [moment formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: Thq @VincenzoC. format is for Bootstrap Multiselect. I am talking about Wicket DateTimeField component which comes packed with date text, calendar, hours and minutes fields..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using DateTextField in place of DateTimeField? In this way you could have one field with, for example, dd/MM/yyyy.
Look at the example [here](http://examples-wickettutorial.rhcloud.com/wicket/bookmarkable/org.wicketTutorial.datepicker.HomePage) where you can see an example of custom DateTextField with a JQuery calendar.

Comment: Yes @Andrea Del Bene. Using DateTextField is giving both text field and calendar together. As i wanted to get rid of calendar I opted for plain text box and call bootstrap datepicker JS function on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wicket Bootstrap (https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap).
Examples at: http://wb-mgrigorov.rhcloud.com/datetimepicker
Implementation: https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/tree/wicket-7.x/bootstrap-extensions/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/extensions/markup/html/bootstrap/form/datetime

Comment: Thank you martin-g. I will implement and let you know. I am trying to adapt to the code used in my project where they had used DateTimeField. Now I replaced that with TextField. Couple of models are associated with my date component as well.